# Error en Expo (Undefined Promise Rejection)

Tags: react-native, expo

estoy desarrollando una APP en `react-native` con `Expo` todo iba bien hasta que instale un modulo que no era compatible, la cuestion es que lo desinstale, elimine node_modules, y ejecute `npm install`, ya intente también ejecutar expo reseteando el cache del packager pero nada, cuando carga la app me salen esos errores amarillos.

```js
17:24:44: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: File '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/98126621-9112-4E90-8841-8B5285A52444/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Ftestapp-d108144b-6d30-4889-a75b-2fcc1a626091/ExponentAsset-5673da52c98bb6cb33ada5aaf649703e.ttf' for font '9BFE629D-F610-42DE-A03A-E34074A10E08-Roboto' doesn't exist]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:121:42 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:78:57 in <unknown>
- ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals
17:24:47: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: File '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/98126621-9112-4E90-8841-8B5285A52444/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Ftestapp-d108144b-6d30-4889-a75b-2fcc1a626091/ExponentAsset-a37b0c01c0baf1888ca812cc0508f6e2.ttf' for font '9BFE629D-F610-42DE-A03A-E34074A10E08-material' doesn't exist]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:121:42 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:78:57 in <unknown>
- ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals
17:24:47: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: File '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/98126621-9112-4E90-8841-8B5285A52444/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Ftestapp-d108144b-6d30-4889-a75b-2fcc1a626091/ExponentAsset-a37b0c01c0baf1888ca812cc0508f6e2.ttf' for font '9BFE629D-F610-42DE-A03A-E34074A10E08-material' doesn't exist]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:121:42 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:78:57 in <unknown>
- ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals
17:24:50: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: File '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/98126621-9112-4E90-8841-8B5285A52444/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Ftestapp-d108144b-6d30-4889-a75b-2fcc1a626091/ExponentAsset-a37b0c01c0baf1888ca812cc0508f6e2.ttf' for font '9BFE629D-F610-42DE-A03A-E34074A10E08-material' doesn't exist]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:121:42 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:78:57 in <unknown>
- ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Este es el código de mi `App.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Login from './views/Login/Login.js';
import HomePage from './views/Landing/Landing.js';
import Settings from './views/Settings/Settings.js';
import { View, Button, StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Font } from 'expo';
import { COLOR, ThemeContext, getTheme } from 'react-native-material-ui';
import MainHeader from './components/MainHeader/MainHeader.js';
import Styles from './App.scss';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

const uiTheme = {
  palette: {
    primaryColor: COLOR.green500,
  },
  toolbar: {
    container: {
      height: 50,
    },
  },
};

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'Roboto': require('./fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
  });
}


class Landing extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
  };
  static navigationOptions = { title: 'Inicio', header: null };

  async _loadAssetsAsync() {
  
    const fontAssets = cacheFonts();

    await Promise.all([...fontAssets]);
  }

  render() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() { self.setState({isReady: true})}, '1000')
    if (this.state.isReady) {
        return (
         <HomePage navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        );
      }else{
        this._loadAssetsAsync();
        return (
          <View style={Styles.loader}>
            <Text h1 style={Styles.text}>Un segundo, la aplicación se esta cargando</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
}


const App = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Landing },
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Settings: { screen: Settings }
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  headerMode: 'screen'
});


export default App;
```

Básicamente lo que hago es esperar unos segundos a que se carguen las fuentes y luego ejecuto la APP. No se que pueda estar ocurriendo aquí.

Comment: Hola Santiago, este error es en iOS o Android?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que al instalar ese módulo no compatible haya cambiado la configuración de tu proyecto, quedando *linkeados* recursos (en este caso, fonts) que luego borraste y ya no existen.

Te recomiendo:

1. Si fuiste versionando tu código, revisar el commit donde instalaste el módulo y ver qué cambio en el archivo `project.pbxproj`.
2. Si no, hacer un search de `9BFE629D-F610-42DE-A03A-E34074A10E08-Roboto` en todo tu proyecto para ver si puedes quitar esas referencias manualmente.